# Eigen with -O3 warning: argument 1 value ‘X’ exceeds maximum object size Y

Tags: c++, memory, eigen, gcc-warning, eigen3

### What happens

When I try to add an `Eigen::Vector3f` into an `std::vector` following the tutorial [on Eigen website](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
#include <iostream>

template <class EigenT>
using EigenStdVector = std::vector<EigenT, Eigen::aligned_allocator<EigenT>>;

int main() {
  EigenStdVector<Eigen::Vector3f> vec;
  vec.emplace_back(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  std::cerr << vec.back().transpose() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
In file included from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:349:0,
                 from /home/igor/Code/eigen_example/example.cpp:3:
In function ‘void* Eigen::internal::aligned_malloc(std::size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_realloc_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _Args&& ...) [with _Args = {float, float, float}; _Tp = Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1>; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> >]’ at /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:742:76:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:159:12: warning: argument 1 value ‘18446744073709551612’ exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]
     result = std::malloc(size);
```

### How to reproduce

I am on **Ubuntu 18.04** and have **Eigen 3.3.4** installed.

You can build the code in this question with the following command if you have Eigen installed with the following command:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -O3 example.cpp
```

### What triggers the warning

- The warning only shows when using `Vector2f`, `Vector3f`, etc. It is not shown for types like `Matrix2f`, `Matrix3f`, etc.
- The warning is shown whenever I have `-O[1-3]` enabled and does not happen with `-O0`

### Further info:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47450718/gcc7-2-argument-range-exceeds-maximum-object-size-9-7-werror-alloc-size-larg) seems to be related, but I don't see how it could help me.

I have made a small example for everyone who wants a ready-to-run example. You can find it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/niosus/eigen-warning-example).

Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: That value is 2^64-4, which is surely relevant.

Comment: What version of Eigen are you using? (Check in `/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/util/Macros.h`) And can you give a one-line compiler command, instead of the CMakelist? (build with `VERBOSE=1`)

Comment: @chtz I have updated the question. Just for simplicity will double relevant info here. Version of Eigen: 3.3.4, a command to build the code to reproduce this: `g++ -I/usr/include/eigen3 -O3 example.cpp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h` in the implementation of `Eigen::aligned_allocator` these lines can be found:

```
#if EIGEN_COMP_GNUC_STRICT && EIGEN_GNUC_AT_LEAST(7,0)
// In gcc std::allocator::max_size() is bugged making gcc triggers a warning:
// eigen/Eigen/src/Core/util/Memory.h:189:12: warning: argument 1 value '18446744073709551612' exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807
// See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87544
size_type max_size() const {
  return (std::numeric_limits<std::ptrdiff_t>::max)()/sizeof(T);
}
#endif
```

So, it seems that this is connected to [this GCC bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87544).

As far as I can see, the [commit](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/90173cbfea144ccbbc7d687ffaa322e6e67a4e0e) fixing this appeared on 2018-10-07, and should be available in Eigen 3.3.6.