# Argument mismatch when there doesn't seem to be any

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

I'm trying to write a program to find the determinant of an NxN matrix, and in doing so, learning about `std::array` and `templates` for the first time.

I came up with this implementation, based on the method of cofactors and minor.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, N>, N>;

template <int N>
Matrix<N - 1> subMatrix(Matrix<N> matrix, size_t focusRow, size_t focusColumn) {
    Matrix<N - 1> returnMatrix;

    int subMatrixRow = 0, subMatrixColumn = 0;
    static const int matrixSize = matrix.size();

    for (size_t matrixRow = 0; matrixRow < matrixSize; matrixRow++) {
        for (size_t matrixColumn = 0; matrixColumn < matrixSize; matrixColumn++) {
            if (matrixRow != focusRow && matrixColumn != focusColumn) {
                returnMatrix[subMatrixRow][subMatrixColumn++] = matrix[matrixRow][matrixColumn];

                if (subMatrixColumn == matrixSize - 1) {
                    subMatrixColumn = 0;
                    subMatrixRow++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnMatrix;
}

template <int N>
double getDeterminant(Matrix<N> matrix) {
    static const int matrixSize = matrix.size();
    double determinant = 0;

    if (matrixSize == 1) {
        determinant = matrix[0][0];
    }

    else if (matrixSize == 2) {
        determinant = (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
    }

    else if (matrixSize > 0) {
        int sign = 1;

        for (size_t dimension = 0; dimension < N; dimension++) {
            determinant += sign * matrix[0][dimension] * getDeterminant(subMatrix(matrix, 0, dimension));
            sign = -sign;
        }
    }

    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected square matrix");
    }

    return determinant;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    static const int length = 3;

    Matrix<length> matrix = {{{1, 2, 3},
                              {4, 5, 6},
                              {7, 8, 9}}};

    printf("determinant = %.2f\n", getDeterminant(matrix));
}
```

However, when I run `make`, I get an error I'm not quite able to resolve. How to proceed?

```bash
vscode ➜ /workspaces/c-cpp-mirror/11032023-arrays $ make determinant
g++     determinant.cpp   -o determinant
determinant.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:
determinant.cpp:68:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘getDeterminant(Matrix<3>&)’
   68 |     printf("determinant = %.2f\n", getDeterminant(matrix));
      |                                                         ^
determinant.cpp:31:8: note: candidate: ‘template<int N> double getDeterminant(Matrix<N>)’
   31 | double getDeterminant(Matrix<N> matrix) {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
determinant.cpp:31:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
determinant.cpp:68:57: note:   mismatched types ‘int’ and ‘long unsigned int’
   68 |     printf("determinant = %.2f\n", getDeterminant(matrix));
      |                                                         ^
make: *** [<builtin>: determinant] Error 1
```

---

Here's a smaller program that still exhibits the same behaviour:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, N>, N>;

template <int N>
void printMatrix(Matrix<N> matrix) {}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    static const int length = 4;

    Matrix<length> matrix = {{{7, -2, 2, 1},
                              {3, 1, -5, 2},
                              {2, 2, -5, 3},
                              {3, 2, 5, 1}}};

    printMatrix(matrix);
}
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, I just realised that after posting too. Have edited, thanks!

Comment: `std::array`'s size argument type is  `std::size_t` and not `int`. Mixing the two might be messing with template argument deduction, and since no arguments are provided explicitly the compiler can't find a function it can call.

Comment: This is not minimal, see [mre].

Comment: Clang has a better diagnostic: _"candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced non-type template argument does not have the same type as the corresponding template parameter ('unsigned long' vs 'int')"_

Comment: @PasserBy this is fair critique. Please allow a few minutes, I'll try to minimize the example.

Comment: @PasserBy I've added a separate smaller example. However, I didn't remove the original code because it prompted an important point in the accepted answer (regarding `constexpr`) which was vital to solving the problem. Please advise if this seems okay

Comment: The new example is much better. Leaving the original there is correct, otherwise the answer would not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple fundamental issues with the shown code.

The first one is that`std::array`'s 2nd template parameter is not an `int`. It's a `std::size_t`.

Put this fact in a blender, together with a `using` alias, swirl it around, and you end up in, basically, asking a suffering C++ compiler to deduce an `int` from a `size_t`. It's an apple vs oranges problem.

To fix this first problem, all template `template<int N>` declarations must be changed to `template<size_t n>`.

But when this happens your compiler will be grumpy, because you will be instructing your suffering C++ compiler to create a matrix with more values than there are atoms in our shared universe:

```
    else if (matrixSize > 0) {
        Matrix<N - 1> temp;
```

When `Matrix` is 0 this will end up being a pretty large Matrix, won't you say? Even though this branch will not be taken, this still has to compile, and as a template your suffering C++ compiler needs to, basically, evaluate it. The chances of that are not very likely.

So, you need to fix that, and change all of these to `if constexpr`.

Then, the code will compile.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t N>
using Matrix = std::array<std::array<double, N>, N>;

template <std::size_t N>
Matrix<N - 1> subMatrix(Matrix<N> matrix, size_t focusRow, size_t focusColumn) {
    Matrix<N - 1> returnMatrix;

    int subMatrixRow = 0, subMatrixColumn = 0;
    static const int matrixSize = matrix.size();

    for (size_t matrixRow = 0; matrixRow < matrixSize; matrixRow++) {
        for (size_t matrixColumn = 0; matrixColumn < matrixSize; matrixColumn++) {
            if (matrixRow != focusRow && matrixColumn != focusColumn) {
                returnMatrix[subMatrixRow][subMatrixColumn++] = matrix[matrixRow][matrixColumn];

                if (subMatrixColumn == matrixSize - 1) {
                    subMatrixColumn = 0;
                    subMatrixRow++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnMatrix;
}

template <std::size_t N>
double getDeterminant(Matrix<N> matrix) {
    static const int matrixSize = matrix.size();
    double determinant;

    if constexpr (matrixSize == 1) {
        determinant = matrix[0][0];
    }

    else if constexpr (matrixSize == 2) {
        determinant = (matrix[0][0] * matrix[1][1]) - (matrix[0][1] * matrix[1][0]);
    }

    else if constexpr (matrixSize > 0) {
        Matrix<N - 1> temp;
        int sign = 1;

        for (size_t dimension = 0; dimension < N; dimension++) {
            temp = subMatrix(matrix, 0, dimension);
            determinant += sign * matrix[0][dimension] * getDeterminant(temp);
            sign = -sign;
        }
    }

    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected square matrix");
    }

    return determinant;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    static const int length = 3;

    Matrix<length> matrix = {{{1, 2, 3},
                         {4, 5, 6},
                         {7, 8, 9}}};

    printf("determinant = %.2f\n", getDeterminant(matrix));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Indeed, I had tried `std::size_t` first, but it gave [these exceptions](https://pastebin.com/vaV4FYR4) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/63372812/10907280 directed me to use `int`. Your explanation with pointing to `N - 1` helps a lot here.

Comment: Yes. I didn't immediately see the 2nd issue. After fixing the first compilation error this exact error came up. In C++ there can be different reasons for the same error. It takes time to learn how to understand compiler errors. Don't take the results of a search blindly without reading it and fully understanding how it applies to one's own code.